# Installing mdb-react-ui-kit

Tags: reactjs, npm

i typed in my terminal "npm i mdb-react-ui-kit" but this error showed.

```
PS C:\Users\asus\Desktop\web clone> npm i mdb-react-ui-kit
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: travel-react-app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^18.1.0" from mdb-react-ui-kit@6.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/mdb-react-ui-kit
npm ERR!   mdb-react-ui-kit@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-09T02_18_54_224Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-09-09T02_18_54_224Z-debug-0.log
```

i tried installing the npm to a different project with no errors

Comment: `Fix the upstream dependency conflict`

Answer (score 0):

Use this to install mdb-react-ui-kit

> npm i mdb-react-ui-kit --legacy-peer-deps

OR

Change version of `react` to `18.1.0` in your `package.json` and run `npm install` again.